# Return result view by name in Application.java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

In a Play 2.2! web project I'm pursuing, I'd like to return views by name in Application.java

I've added the following in the routes config :

```
GET     /:page                      controllers.Application.show(page: String)
```

And i'd like Application.java to return the correct view only using it's name (the String page).

At the moment I have :

```
public static Result show(String page) {
    switch(page){
        case "home":
            return ok(home.render());
        case "register":
            return ok(register.render());
    }
    return ok(home.render());
}
```

I'd like to avoid the switch statement here, and have show(String page) programatically find the view that matches the String page given in argument and return it (or home page if no match has been found).

EDIT : I've read some stuff about reflexion but I don't really know what that is or how to use it :/

Thanks for your insight :)

Comment: None of them takes parameters ? they are just HTML files to display ?

Comment: Yes they don't need parameters for now (I used "register" as an example, It's not really a registration page for now, just plain html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Play's view is a Scala function - which takes parameters, for ensuring **typesafety**, **dynamic content** etc, etc. In this scenario you shouldn't use `:path` argument but make usage of different routes to different actions like:

```
GET     /home           controllers.Application.home
GET     /register       controllers.Application.register
```

Actions:

```
public static Result home() {
    return ok(home.render());
}

public static Result register() {
    return ok(register.render());
}
```

*Crypto-advertisment: Use Intellij - create templates for actions and routes and you will be doing it within milliseconds ;)*

On the other hand if you have a large set of HTML files you can render them as... files instead of Play views like (*pseudo code, debug it yourself!*)

```
public static Result show(String page) {

    File htmlFile = new File(page+".html");
    if (!htmlFile.exists()) htmlFile = new File("home.html");

    return ok(htmlFile).as("text/html");
}
```

I will only add that is **absolutely NOT** Play's way for working with *templates* ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :)

I'll take your advices into consideration concerning Play's way.

I'm new to play & html/css so for now I mostly do static pages and I'll make the app eveole to more dynamic content when I'll get better at it :)

Comment: If you are starting you'll do better deal if you FIRST go with way documented in official docs, it's precious. Of course you can also use other approaches, but.. don't enforce avoiding good practices at the beginning (that's my experience)

Comment: I've followed your advice and went the "Play way" (I made a different route for each action). Thanks again :)